# How to use ng-polymer-elements to have decoupled 2-way binding?

Tags: angularjs, binding, scope, polymer

I'm looking at the [implementation examples](http://gabiaxel.github.io/ng-polymer-elements/) for ng-polymer-element. Maybe I'm confused, but I'm trying to find a way of 2-way binding a custom Polymer element in a decoupled way? Do these only work with core/paper elements? Am I barking up the wrong tree?

How would I do an "isolated scope" style binding?

Such as the following (which doesn't actually do 2-way binding):

```
<some-input ng-model="someCtrl.testModel.name"></some-input>

<!-- then in the custom element -->

<polymer-element name="some-input">
    <template>
        <input id="inputField" type="text" model="{{HOW-TO-GET-THE-NG-MODEL???}}" on-click="{{setFocus}}"> 
    </template>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="some-input.js"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

**UPDATE:**

According to the [constants mappings](https://github.com/GabiAxel/ng-polymer-elements/blob/master/ng-polymer-elements.js) it seems that there is a default ngModel binding to value (as seen from the custom element)... I'm unable to access it from inside the input though.....

So HOW would I bind to value? I've tried

```
 <some-input ng-model="workbenchCtrl.testModel.name"></some-input>

<!-- inside custom element -->
<input id="inputField" type="text" model="{{value}}" on-click="{{setFocus}}">
```

but it comes up blank.

Comment: I have a working solution using a different library, however, I'd still like to see how this pans out. If you're curious, I got https://github.com/eee-c/angular-bind-polymer angular-bind-polymer to work as described (but you can't use it with core or paper elements).

Comment: So, I'd like to get ng-polymer-elements working since, unfortunately, angular-bind-polymer ONLY WORKS FOR STRINGS!!! (due to MutationObserver[attribute] limitations.

Comment: If your goal is to work with AngularJS and have material design, did you try to work with https://material.angularjs.org/#/ ?

Comment: no, we have complex, domain specific custom components (think data vis and scientific modules) that need to be shared between projects. Not really pursuing "any device" frameworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define new mappings for any element as long as you map properties that are [published](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/binding-types.html#binding-to-polymer-published-properties). See the end of the documentation for how to define new bindings. In your example (assuming you publish "model") you would do something like this:

```
angular.module('ng-polymer-elements').constant('$ngPolymerMappings', {
  someInput: {
    ngModel: {
     primitive: 'model'
    }
 }
});
```

and to use the component:

```
<some-input ng-model="someCtrl.testModel.name"></some-input>
```

note you don't use {{ }} for two way binding.

Comment: yeah, the  {{ }}  was a typo from banging it out quickly in the SO form. I've been able to use angular-bind-polymer with published properties but that is limited to strings. Would ng-polymer-elements bind all types since it uses a PathObserver instead of a MutationObserver?

Comment: ah yeah, an dit seems that ng-polymer-elements depends on angular version 1.3x

Answer (score 0):

```
    * npm install -g yo
    * npm install generator-polymer -g
    * mkdir ng-polymer-test  && cd $_
    * yo polymer
    * npm install  grunt
    * npm install grunt-contrib-watch
    * npm install grunt-replace
    * bower install angular
    * bower install ng-polymer-elements
    * yo polymer:element m-test
    * subl app/index.html

<!doctype html>
<html lang="" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>poly foo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
  <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/ng-polymer-elements/ng-polymer-elements.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">


  <link rel="import" href="elements/elements.html">
  <link rel="import" href="elements/m-test/m-test.html">
</head>

<body unresolved fullbleed layout vertical>
  <div  ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input ng-model="firstname" type="text">
  <paper-input ng-model="firstname"></paper-input>

  <h1>Hello {{ firstname }}</h1>
   <m-test ng-model="firstname" ng-click="myClick()"></m-test>

  </div>
</body>

<script>


var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ng-polymer-elements']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
    $scope.addresses = [{
       "number":"3",
       "street":"main",
    }];

    $scope.myClick = function(event) { alert('Hello'); }; 

});

angular.module('ng-polymer-elements').constant('$ngPolymerMappings', {
   mTest: {
      ngModel: {
         primitive: 'firstname'
      },
      ngClick: {
         event: 'someEvent'
      }

   }
});

</script>

</html>

     * subl app/elements/m-test/m-test.html

    <link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="m-test" attributes="">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
    Hello from m-test  {{firstname}}
    <br>

    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="c2" value="c2" id="c2" onchange="myonchange()" >
  </template>
  <script>
    (function () {
      Polymer({
        myonchange:function(){
           this.asyncFire("someEvent",{});
        },
      });
    })();
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```